# How (behind-the-scenes) does Task Scheduler end tasks?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

When Windows' Task Scheduler ends as task (either because the task exceeded the `stop the task if it runs longer than` timeout or because a user right-clicked on it and chose 'End'), what happens behind-the-scenes? Is a WM_CLOSE message sent to the task's executable? Is the OS asked to kill the task?

The fact that a task can be configured to `if the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop` (Task Properties, Settings tab) makes me think that first Task Scheduler sends a 'hey, I'd like you to close' message (like WM_CLOSE) to the executing task, then, if that message isn't acted on in a timely manner *and* if the 'force stop' option is configured, the OS is asked to kill the process.

I haven't been able to find documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is handled by the [Unified Background Process Manager](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/10/04/windows-7-windows-server-2008-r2-unified-background-process-manager-ubpm.aspx), however there is no official documentation that I know of that goes in to detail about that processes.

However, if you are willing to accept *semi-offical* documentation the book [Windows Internals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) has [a section](https://books.google.com/books?id=w65CAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT519&ots=4Wn2p1UpWy&dq=windowsinternals%20task%20scheduler&pg=PT519#v=onepage&q=windowsinternals%20task%20scheduler&f=false) about it in the "Management Mechanisms" chapter.